# Computing derived functor of a complex with non-acyclic terms

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, derived-categories, derived-functors

Let $A^\bullet =(\dots\to A^i\to A^{i+1}\to\dots)$ be a bounded below complex in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ with sufficiently many injectives. Let $F\colon \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ be an additive left exact functor to another abelian category with sufficiently many injectives. Let $DF\colon D^+\mathcal{A}\to D^+\mathcal{B}$ be the induced functor between the derived categories.

Assume in addition that for any $k>0$ the complex
$$\dots\to R^kF(A^i)\to R^kF(A^{i+1})\to \dots$$
is exact, where $R^kF\colon \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ denotes the $k$th derived functor.

> Is it true that the complex  $$\dots\to F(A^i)\to F(A^{i+1})\to\dots$$
>   is isomorphic to $RF(A^\bullet)$ in $D^+(\mathcal{B})$?

A reference will be helpful.

Remarks. (1) In my situation $\mathcal{A}$ is the category of sheaves of vector spaces on a smooth manifold, and $F$ is the functor of global sections with support in a closed subset.

(2) One may assume in addition that there exists $N$ such that $R^kF(A^i)=0$ for all $k>N$ and $i\in \mathbb{Z}$.

(3) This question is known to have a positive answer if one makes a much stronger assumption that
$$R^kF(A^i)=0 \mbox{ for all } i\in \mathbb{Z}, k>0.$$